# IE 9 Error on dot length property of an AJAX response data object; using jquery 1.10.2

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

Here is the error: `Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference`

Is there a fix without rewriting this code. I know could use a `$.each` to maybe fix this, but is there some work around without fixing the code below. When it gets to data.length in the loop it breaks.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "api_build_left_nav",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var current_category = 'not_defined';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (current_category !== data[i].category) {
                    $(".menu_roll_out_content").append("<h2 class='left_nav_header'>" + data[i].category + "</h2>");
                    current_category = data[i].category;
                    $(".menu_roll_out_content").append("<dt class='left_nav_link'><a href=" + data[i].href + ">" + data[i].report + "</a></dt>");
                } else {
                    $(".menu_roll_out_content").append("<dt class='left_nav_link'><a href=" + data[i].href + ">" + data[i].report + "</a></dt>");
                } // end else
            } // end for loop 
        }, // end success fn
        error: function(error) {}
    }); // end ajax call
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the json formatted data into a JavaScript object first before iterating it through:

```
var data = JSON.parse(data);
```